# PKDrawing: Text to PKStroke

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit

I would like to add text to a `PKDrawing`

Apple actually demonstrates this use case in their WWDC2020 video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10148

However, looking at the sample code, they simply recorded previously drawn text

Anyone familiar with fonts and vector formats: what would be a good approach to converting a single system font to `PKStroke` for adding to a `PKDrawing`?

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to add a custom `UIView` into the background of `PKCanvasView` and handle the drawing there, where you have 100% freedome

Turning a `UIFont` into a representation of `PKDrawing` would be almost impossible to get right, as `PKDrawing`/`PKStroke` represent Pen input (**the only way i could thing of would be to fake a solid drawn rectangle and use the mask bezier to cut out the letter(s)**)